# How does the plug-in get the current version number of host vscode？

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My plug-in is special, which needs to be tested according to the version number of the vscode installed by the user so as to update the version. If the version number of the user's vscode does not meet the version number required by the plug-in, the plug-in needs to be automatically updated and upgraded.

My plugin was installed from a vsix file, not from the official app market

Answer (score 0):

import * as vscode from 'vscode';

console.log(vscode.version); // "1.27.1"